# Find previous/next records when given alphabetic order in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `people`

```
id    name
----+-----
54    Tango
76    Alpha
95    Radio
```

When displaying the records on the web those names are ordered alphabetically

```
Alpha, Radio, Tango
```

Lets say we're viewing `Radio` details and want to navigate to the next `(Tango)` or prevoius `(Alpha)` record using some links.

How can I find those `id's` to create the needed links?

Finding next superior or inferior `id` won't work.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
   SELECT name, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) rank
   FROM people, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t
   ORDER BY name
) t WHERE rank = @n
```

You should use the new ranking number column `rank` to create those links. Then you should control the value of the parameter `@n` to get the previous or the next.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fee74/6)

Comment: @Mahmoud  is this just [useful or brilliant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords/161869#161869) on the mission of a feature request :)

Comment: @bonCodigo For my it will be useful and brilliant feature. I always suffer from this issue. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal great to hear that. BTW there was one good answer from you. It was about parent-child query. You used `partition` to make *levels* and then group by those.. And I remember commenting. I went thorough most of the comments but unable to find it. If you don't mind could you please give me the link? (given you remember.. ;))

Comment: @bonCodigo What about some SQL? [**This query**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/91321/what-was-those-answers-that-you-have-commented-on) will give you all my answers that you had commented on. From your description there was many answers of this type, but the best one is [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738865/tricky-select-statement/13739320#13739320) as I remember. However, if you are sure it contains the `PARTITION BY` clause, [**These answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A722783+[sql]+Partition+by) are all that contains `PARTITION BY` on it.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal this is mind blowing. I didn't know we can query stack db.. awesome.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I am not kidding but it's something I ddnt know really. That I can query from stack db to find questions and answers that I may have interacted with..

Comment: @MahmoudGamal the links you gave were helpful but no luck yet. I am not sure now if it was yours or Gordon Lindoff's. But I have tried his as well. It was a query about getting min max in two columns. What you did was you gave a row number to a group, and then you picked the min max. That was one great logic. I really would like to find it. I remember saying that I would want to vote more than one if possible. Sorry I know pretty vague description...for a search key. Only I wish if that feature had been released.

Comment: @bonCodigo I saw this several times, I am not sure if I did this before or not. I saw JW and bluefeet do this several times, I will find one for you.

Comment: @bonCodigo What about [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907301/sql-values-for-min-and-max-rows-in-one-row/13907410#13907410)

Answer (score 5):

it is not done so yet.

prev

```
SELECT Id FROM people WHERE name < 'Radio' ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1
```

next

```
SELECT Id FROM people WHERE name > 'Radio' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That would work for SQL Server, but he's using MySQL. You can use LIMIT, in such case.

Comment: No, there is no TOP, it's not ANSI SQL. The new answer is correct. :)

Comment: FWIW, `LIMIT` syntax is not defined by ANSI SQL either.  But it works in MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL as a useful extension to SQL.

Comment: I can't believe I haven't tried this one.. it works but it's not enough because names can repeat. As you may notice I used simple names to illustrate the idea.

Comment: As you wish, you can use Id in where clause.

Comment: @BillKarwin I know that LIMIT is also not ANSI SQL, I was just pointing out that TOP would not work in this case, as the solution should be for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan this saved me today! (yes, eight years later!)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the previous name with max().

```
select max(name) as name
from people
where name < 'Radio';
```

Then you can use that query as a derived table in a JOIN.

```
select id
from people
inner join 
  (select max(name) as name
   from people
   where name < 'Radio') as t2 on t2.name = people.name
```

Next name is similar, using min() and the `>` operator.

If your design allows duplicate names, the derived table will return multiple rows. That's a problem generally for artificial keys.

What does *next* mean when you start with {100, 'Obama'}, and your data includes

```
{ 50, 'Romney'}
{150, 'Romney'}
{843, 'Romney'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If names can repeat, how do you identify the row that is "current" when you want to find the previous and next row?  I assume you identify it by id.  In any case, you need to have some way to address rows uniquely.

I tested this:

```
USE test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO t (id, name) VALUES
(54, 'Tango'),
(76, 'Alpha'),
(78, 'Alpha'),
(95, 'Radio');

(SELECT * FROM t WHERE id >= 76 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM t WHERE id <= 76 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

UNION takes care of eliminating the duplicate row where id=76

Here's the result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 54 | Tango |
| 76 | Alpha |
| 78 | Alpha |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cleanest and most efficient way:
To get next:

```
 select min(name) people where name > 'RADIO';
```

To get previous:

```
 select max(name) people where name < 'RADIO';
```