# SQL values for min and max rows in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with price changes and I need to get initial price and latest price.
In other words I want to display price values for min(StartDate) and max(StartDate) in one row for each product.

Table structure is simple:

```
ProductID, StartDate, Price
```

Desired result is

```
ProductId, StartDate, InitialPrice, LatestDate, LatestPrice
```

Comment: Does MS SQL Server have a GREATEST() function?  If so, use it, and the matching LEAST() which it would presumably also have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH latestPrice AS
(
   SELECT ProductID, StartDate, Price,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PArtition BY ProductID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) rn
   FROM TableName
)
, initalPrice AS
(
  SELECT ProductID, StartDate, Price,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PArtition BY ProductID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) rn
  FROM TableName  
)
SELECT  a.ProductID,
        b.StartDate, 
        b.Price InitalPrice, 
        c.StartDate LatestDate, 
        c.Price LatestPrice
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM tableName) a
        INNER JOIN initalPrice b
          ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID AND b.rn = 1
        INNER JOIN latestprice c
          ON a.ProductID = c.ProductID AND c.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c47c/18)

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks, actually this is my first trial, i've been browsing on sql server docs to find some built-in function to make the query shorter `:D`

Comment: @JW Thanks, it seems to be working but it's quite complex for me to digest. First time seeing WITH and PARTITION BY. However I also came up with this, what do you think? `SELECT id1, id2, MIN(date1), MAX(date2) FROM 
(
  SELECT ProductID id1, MIN(StartDate) date1, Price p1
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY ProductID, Price
) A
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ProductID id2, MAX(StartDate) date2, Price p2
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY ProductID, Price
) B

ON B.id2 = A.id1
GROUP BY id1, id2`

Comment: the `WITH` you see is called `Common Table Expression`. `Partition By`, searched for `Window Function`. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT x.ProductId, x.MinStartDate, x.MinPrice, y.MaxStartDate, y.MaxPrice FROM (SELECT a.ProductId, a.MinStartDate, b.Price AS MinPrice FROM (SELECT ProductId, MIN(StartDate) AS MinStartDate FROM Products GROUP BY ProductId) a INNER JOIN Products b ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId AND a.MinStartDate = b.StartDate) x INNER JOIN (SELECT a.ProductId, a.MaxStartDate, b.Price AS MaxPrice FROM (SELECT ProductId, MAX(StartDate) AS MaxStartDate FROM Products GROUP BY ProductId) a INNER JOIN Products b ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId AND a.MaxStartDate = b.StartDate) y ON x.ProductId = y.ProductId
```

DISCLAIMER: This is from memory so I apologize if this is not entirely accurate. And it assumes that the StartDate is a datetime or is not repeated for each productId.

Hope this helps.